# Rails dataTables have to reload page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using dataTables in a Rails app.  I have a model called `site`.

The index for `site` uses a dataTable to list the sites.

When I first load the index page

```
http://localhost:3000/sites
```

The dataTable doesn't work.  There are no console errors.

If I reload the page, it works!

During the reload, the console shows entries like this:

```
Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-13 17:24:29 -0600
Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-13 17:24:29 -0600
Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-editable.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-13 17:24:29 -0600
Started GET "/assets/ColVis.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-13 17:24:29 -0600
Started GET "/assets/datetimepicker.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-13 17:24:29 -0600
Started GET "/assets/datepicker.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-13 17:24:29 -0600
Started GET "/assets/dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-13 17:24:29 -0600
Started GET "/assets/jquery.qtip.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-13 17:24:30 -0600
Started GET "/assets/jquery.treeTable.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-13 17:24:30 -0600
Started GET "/assets/TableTools.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-13 17:24:30 -0600
Started GET "/assets/TableTools_JUI.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-13 17:24:30 -0600
...
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use gem **turbolink**? If yes, that can be the reason of it, because it do not reload the whole page, just partially. You can solve it in two different ways:

1. Don't use turbolink (but your website will be slower)
2. Move your datatable init code into *page:change*,
   like this in application.js:

   $(document).on("page:change", function() {
      $('#yourtable').dataTable();
   });